# Unity 2d Random Music start only on first time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im programming an simple Unity 2d Game and I want to add some Background music, I have an script that random starts an Title from an playlist, but when im rejoining the MainMenu Scene where the Music GameObject is located, another Song starts playing (2 Songs Playing), but I want that only one song is playing, the song that was first. I saw when I rejoined the MainMenu scene that another music object where created.

here my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicRandom : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AudioClip[] myAudioClips;
    AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start() 
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    }

    AudioClip RandomClip() 
    {
        int randomNumber = Random.Range(0,myAudioClips.Length);
        AudioClip randomClip = myAudioClips[randomNumber];
        return randomClip;
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        if (!audioSource.isPlaying) {
            audioSource.clip = RandomClip();
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add an value that start the "audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent ();" function only one time, but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found an way that the GameObject not duplicate

```
 private static GameObject instance;
 void Start() 
 {
 DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
 if (instance == null)
     instance = gameObject;
 else
     Destroy(gameObject);
 }
```